# My company is asking to do transformations & reporting directly from Azure DW - does this seem like a good idea?

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

My company wants to speed up the process of delivering reports. Internally, we have a team of 12 people working on building reports. The company is a large company with over 10,000 employees. We're asked to work on adhoc reports quite frequently, but it takes us on average 1-2 weeks to deliver these reports. Senior Execs have said that the time to deliver is too slow. An external consulting firm came into to do some discovery work and they have advised that business users should have access to the Azure Data Warehouse, so that they can directly build models in Azure Analysis services and Power BI.

The design that they have suggested is as follows:

1. Load data from SAP, into the Azure Data Warehouse directly.
2. Build our data models in the Azure DW - this means all the transformation work is done directly in Azure DW (Staging, Cleansing, Star Schema build).
3. Build the models in Azure Analysis Services.
4. Consume in Power BI.

Does this seem like a good strategy? I am new to Azure Data Warehouse and our technical lead is on paternity, so we are unable to ask for his help.

I asked the external consultant what the impact would be directly applying all transformation workloads to Azure DW, and he has said that 'it's mpp, so processing is super-fast'.

Can anyone help? My team technical lead is on paternity so we can't get hold of him.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is certainly a great platform for the modern data warehousing and analytics purpose, but ADW or not requires more study. Generally speaking, you can consider two options:

Volume is not huge ( < 10TB ):

- SAP -> SSIS/ADF -> Azure SQL DB -> Azure Analysis Services (as semantic layer) tabular model with DAX -> Power BI

Volume is huge ( > 10TB ):

- SAP -> SSIS/ADF -> Azure SQL DW -> Azure Analysis Services semantic layer -> Power BI

Of course, the volume is just one of many factors to consider when you decide the architecture, but it is an important factor from numerous real-world experiences where MPP may not be really necessary. The actual architecture and sizing require a lot more effort to research. The above points are the very general for your reference, to have something to start with and explore further.

If you look for more technical detail to bring SAP data to Azure, you can review our blog at here http://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2018/2/18/extract-sap-data-to-azure-data-lake-for-scale-out-analytics-in-the-cloud and here http://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2018/4/26/use-azure-data-factory-to-bring-sap-data-to-azure.